# Interesting. Creating and reading RGB values are different in JAVA

Tags: java, image, jpeg, rgb, bufferedimage

Today I went to school and showed this event to my teacher but he didn't understand and amazed.

for "1.jpg",  first I shift right red, green, blue values and print this values. after I shift left all these values, and after the new picture is created."2.jpg"(so the same picture)

finally I look two picture and compare these. these are looks like each other but these are not same. I checked comparing these.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedImage resim=null;
        File f=null;

        try {
            f=new File("C:\\Users\\burak\\Desktop\\javaresim\\1.jpg");
            resim=ImageIO.read(f);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          yük=resim.getHeight();
          gen=resim.getWidth();
          boyut=(gen*yük);


         for(int i=0;i<gen;i++){
              for(int j=0;j<yük;j++){

                  int p=resim.getRGB(i, j);

                  int a=(p&0xff000000)>>24;
                  int r=(p&0x00ff0000)>>16;
                  int g=(p&0x0000ff00)>>8;
                  int b=p&0x0000000ff;

                  System.out.print(r+" ");

                  p=(a<<24)|(r<<16)|(g<<8)|b;
                  resim.setRGB(i, j, p);
              }
         }

         try{
             f=new File("C:\\Users\\burak\\Desktop\\javaresim\\2.jpg");

             ImageIO.write(resim, "jpg", f);

            }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
              } 
           }      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JPEG is usually a "lossy" format (depending on options).  This means that source RGB values are not reproduced **exactly** when stored.  You *can* set the options for your jpeg writing to be loss-less, but that increases file size, and defeats the purpose of using jpeg in the first place.

My guess is that if you were to try this same code for a BMP file, or any loss-less format, the images would be exactly the same.

The fact that you load a compressed image, and then write it back to a compressed format introduces the "copy of a copy" issue.  Your original image was already lossy.  You loaded it in, and then saved it out, again with compression enabled.  Each time this is done, some amount of original information is lost.

It is analogous to taking a picture of a picture.  Each time this is done, you lose information.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps in the JPEG compression process that change the input.

1. Color images are converted from RGB to YCbCr. There is not a 1:1 match between the two color system so values can get clipped.
2. The DCT is a floating point operation carried out on integer values. This results in rounding differences (usually at most +/-1).
3. The quantization process performs integer division on the DCT coefficients, changing many to 0 and dropping off fractions in other values.

The result is an image coming out is rarely exactly what went in.

Comment: ı solved this problem accidentaly.   ImageIO.write(resim, "bmp", f); changing jpg to bmp is making jpg image output again. but the matter is solved. images sizes are equal.